# Deploying application on GAE using eclipse plugin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I deployed my web application on GAE using eclipse plugin. UI is fine but I do not see the data getting populated when I send a request. The application statistics tab shows `Datastore Stored Data` as 0%. What ever write operations I did on the local system do I have to do them again once it is deployed on GAE? That means when I deploy my application on GAE the local data store is not copied on to GAE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.... Local data store is not copied... You need to upload the data in CSV or XML format to populate the data..

Comment: Definitely.. Here it goes....   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

Comment: Its under python. Since I'm using java I did not check that. Any way I'm executing all the write queries again on GAE. Looks like I got some data in there now. Thanks.

Comment: **Datastore Java API** is available for Java developers.. I have been using python everytime.. here goes the doc http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/

Answer (score 1):

Local data created by application is for local use only. It's not intended to be uploaded to GAE. Imagine a scenario, where you have a production application live in production with lots of data, and you upload a new version of the application. Would you like local data to be added or worse replace data in GAE? of course not. Local setup is like a test environment with it's own DB. You can access the data in local using http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/ and it is in a file "WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin"

If there is a special need of course you can upload data from local app to datastore.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload data to the GAE datastore using CSV or XML files if that's your aim. I'm not positive about uploading data from your local server's datastore, but you can find out some more information [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data).